# Nodejs: express does not keep req.query.id if we use listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

This is my code:

```
let observe = (obj: any, fn: any) => new Proxy(obj, {
    set: (obj, key, val) => {
      fn(obj)
      return obj[key] = val;
    }
});

router.use('/', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.query.id

  arrs = observe([], (arr: any) => {
    console.log("current", id)
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    arrs.push(id);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Everything is ok, but `console.log("current", id)` does not work correct.

1- I open this url

```
http://localhost:9000/?id=a
```

2- after one second, I open this url:

```
http://localhost:9000/?id=b
```

3- after five seconds, `id` push to `arrs` and `console.log("current", id)` printed:

```
current b
current b
```

why?!

The correct result most be:

```
current a
current b
```

Comment: arrs is being added to the global object, maybe it's being overwritten?

Comment: `arrs` is a global, so by the time `setTimeout` calls the callback, both calls to `arrs.push` are accessing the second array.

Comment: This is [one type of problem that ESLint can spot for you](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-implicit-globals#global-variable-leaks).

Comment: @Quentin So, How can I fix it?

Comment: Declare a local variable as described in the accepted answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: @Quentin I can't. because I use `arrs` in separate place.

Comment: @ali — Currently you are using a global which is shared between all requests, that isn't working for you so you can't store it there. You haven't explained where you do need to use it and how that relates to the different requests you might get from the same or different users, so we can't really suggest what the right place might be.

Comment: @Quentin I use rabbitmq for connect another server. so I write this code for consume response from another server and after consume, I updated `arrs`. after `arrs` updated, I send `res` to api gateway

Comment: I can't see your RabbitMQ client code, and I'm not all that familiar with its API, but I *assume* that when you send a message to RabbitMQ you get a response that is already associated with that message. Pass `res` to whatever function is dealing with that so it is available to the response handling code. Better yet, wrap it in a promise and `await` it inside your endpoint handler.

Comment: @Quentin I can't use await for rabbitmq. because for one channel I can't handle it.